# Нужна ли запятая перед тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Били долго, а когда перестал сопротивляться — пихнули в грязь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тире ставится при пропущенной местоименной части союза А КОГДА...ТО

Сравнить: Били долго, а когда перестал сопротивляться, то пихнули в грязь.

Тире соответствует паузе, которая соответствует переносу тонического ударения на слово "перестал", что обеспечивает его логическое выделение:

Били дОлго, а когда перестАл сопротивляться — пихнули в грЯзь.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько помнится, в этом случае тире заменяет собой запятую. Это, кажется, называется поглощением одного знака препинания другим.

Comment: Ага. Вот, что нашла: «Тире может ставиться вместо запятой (например, для выделения приложений, в сложном предложении и т. п.), но, если каждый из этих знаков ставится по своим условиям, они не поглощают друг друга».