# Нужна ли запятая перед тире (2)?

Tags: пунктуация

У меня возникли трудности с расстановкой знаков:

> *Сказать, что это была старая книга, — значит не сказать ничего*.

Comment: Был похожий вопрос (но не дупликат): https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/37211/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5

Comment: Еще один похожий вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/37476/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F

Comment: "если каждый из этих знаков ставится по своим условиям, они не поглощают друг друга" (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=261803)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Знаки расставлены верно.

Здесь действует правило: если каждый из этих знаков (запятая и тире) ставится по своим условиям, они не поглощают друг друга.  (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=261803)

Слово "значит" выступает как связка (при сказуемом, выраженном инфинитивом). То же, что «это, есть». Перед связкой «значит», присоединяющей сказуемое к подлежащему, ставится тире. После связки знак препинания не ставится.

В свете идти на любовь – значит идти на верный обман. В. Соллогуб, Метель. У Шекспира есть выражение: понять – значит простить. М. Анчаров, Сода-солнце. **Идти обратно вдоль реки, чтоб наткнуться на знакомую тропу, которая ведет в сосновый бор, – значит потерять день.** В. Тендряков, Находка (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_220&layout=item)

Comment: Понял, большое спасибо.